# Using Decred's atomic swap; "transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response"

Tags: http, rpc-error-25

I am trying to run the initiate command according to the example at https://github.com/decred/atomicswap

This is my input:
$ btcatomicswap --testnet --rpcuser=myuser --rpcpass=mypass initiate n3GPmHiV1MieHSN1s8zFDGEbVCpTYWRyFX 1.0

after getting errors and correcting the port, now it says 
getrawchangeaddress: Post http://localhost:18334: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02\x16"

What does this parsing error mean? At what stage of the RPC connection is it faulting? Any help is appreciated :)